# Указатель на обьект класса как поле в другом классе

Tags: c++, ооп

У меня есть класс GameWindow, который из конструктора должен получить указатель на массив типа Block, который является дочерним классом Entity, и сохранить у себя, то есть:

```
class GameWindow { 

Block*  blockConstruct; на этой строке ошибка
Entity* something; нет ошибки
...
};
```

Но компилятор выдаёт ошибку в духе "Синтаксическая ошибка...", да и "Ошибка C4430   отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. "

При этом header класса Block заинклюден...

Помогите, пожалуйста =)

Comment: Так делать конечно можно. Покажите больше кода (см. [mcve]). Может забыли заинклудить сюда хедер с классом Block, или объявить его?

Comment: Добавьте `forward declaration` для `Block` либо подключите заголовочный файл.

Comment: @MaximTimakov, вы правы. Я "гений" у которого класс GameWindow обьяляется раньше нежели Block... Спасибо!